# material design lite textbox on previously hidden div

Tags: material-design-lite

So I'm upgrading my website to use google MDL and having a hang of a time when I know I shouldn't be.

I have identical 2 divs, both contain an MDL-tagged textbox. The only difference is that div B is hidden (using a class called 'hide', with css of display:none).

```
   <div id='a'>
     <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1">Text...</label>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div id='b' class='hide'>
     <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1">Text...</label>
     </div>
   </div>
```

When the page is loaded the textbox in div A has MDL styling as expected. When I show div B via $('#b').show() the textbox does *not* show MDL styling.

How do I get the textbox in div B to have the MDL formatting applied to it?

Calling componentHandler.upgradeDom(); after the div B is shown does nothing.

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm having trouble with Safari when dynamically adding content and calling upgradeDom() whereas Chrome works fine.

Comment: chrome. The below hack from @ASmith seems to work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been running the following script when I make runtime changes to the UI. The script itself is extracted from the MDL material.js and so far it seems to do the trick.  Try calling this script after your code renders the UI or after a 'change' event is fired.  Good luck!

```
function registerMaterialLite() 
            {
                'use strict';
                if ('classList' in document.createElement('div') && 'querySelector' in document && 'addEventListener' in window && Array.prototype.forEach) 
                {
                    document.documentElement.classList.add('mdl-js');
                    componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    componentHandler.upgradeElement = function() {};
                    componentHandler.register = function() {};
                }
            }
```